# TFS 2013 - Create A TFS Group With Rights Only For Managing Work Items

Tags: tfs

Is it possible to create a TFS Group / role where users in that group **can only manage work items** but **not check in code**?

If so,  how would you go about doing this and what permissions does this role need?

I want this for my Project Managers / Business Analysts.

Comment: Sure. Create a new group and then assign the permissions. Just make sure these folks don't end up in the default Reader or Contributor groups.

Comment: @jessehouwing but what are the permissions that will meet my needs?  That is what i'm after.

Answer (score 0):

To enable permissions to manage work items, please go to Settings in Team Explorer and select **Work Item Areas** and **Work Item Iterations**.

[image]

Then on the admin/_areas page (like http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Agile/_admin/_areas), right-click the Area and select **Security**. Set the **Edit work items in this node** and **View work item in this node** to be **Allow**. You then should do the similar settings to Iterations.
[image]

To disable permissions to access source control code: right click the project in **Source Control Explorer** and select **Advanced** -> **Security** to deny source control related permissions:
[image]